# Spark can't identify the event time column being supplied to withWatermark()

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I was trying to find a way to resessionize features in different events based on the event timestamps using Spark and I found a code example that uses `mapGroupsWithState`to resessionize events using processing timestamps in their repo.

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.3.0/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/sql/streaming/StructuredSessionization.scala

To quickly test if this sessionization thing works with event timestamps, I added withWatermark("timestamp", "10 seconds") (treating processing time as the event timestamp) and changed `ProcessingTimeTimeout` to `EventTimeTimeout`.

```
  val lines = spark.readStream
  .format("socket")
  .option("host", host)
  .option("port", port)
  .option("includeTimestamp", value = true)
  .load()

 // Split the lines into words, treat words as sessionId of events
 val events = lines
  .withWatermark("timestamp", "10 seconds") // added
  .as[(String, Timestamp)]
  .flatMap { case (line, timestamp) =>
    line.split(" ").map(word => Event(sessionId = word, timestamp))
  }

 val sessionUpdates = events
  .groupByKey(event => event.sessionId)
  .mapGroupsWithState[SessionInfo, SessionUpdate].(GroupStateTimeout.EventTimeTimeout) {
   ...
  }

  // Start running the query that prints the session updates to the console
 val query = sessionUpdates
  .writeStream
  .outputMode("update")
  .format("console")
  .start()

 query.awaitTermination()
```

However,when I ran it, Spark threw  `org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException` and said that

> Watermark must be specified in the query using '[Dataset/DataFrame].withWatermark()' for using event-time timeout in a [map|flatMap]GroupsWithState. Event-time timeout not supported without watermark`

which is not true and confusing, because that 'timestamp' column is clearly in the physical plan following that exception message:

```
...
+- EventTimeWatermark timestamp#3: timestamp, interval 10 seconds
   +- StreamingRelation DataSource(org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession@394a6d2b,socket,List(),..., [value#2, timestamp#3]
```

Did I miss something or did something wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the water mark after the flatmap operation. 
This should work:

```
val events = lines
  .as[(String, Timestamp)]
  .flatMap { case (line, timestamp) =>
    line.split(" ").map(word => Event(sessionId = word, timestamp))
  }.withWatermark("timestamp", "10 seconds") 

 val sessionUpdates = events
  .groupByKey(event => event.sessionId)
  .mapGroupsWithState[SessionInfo, SessionUpdate].(GroupStateTimeout.EventTimeTimeout) {
   ...
  }
```